# aws cli lambda `update-function-configuration` deletes existing environment variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, environment-variables, aws-cli

The documentation on the [AWS cil lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-configuration.html) states that

`...You provide only the parameters you want to change...`

Which I assume means that the rest of the settings would still remain the same.
However, say my lambda function has environment variables :

```
var1=old_val1
var2=old_val2
var3=old_val3
```

and then when I try doing something like this :

```
aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name dummy_fun --environment '{"Variables":{"var1":"new_val1","var2":"new_val2"}}'
```

with the intention of updating the variables :
**var1** and **var2** with the new values **new_val1** and **new_val2** respectively, although these 2 variables *DO* get updated, but the third one, **var3**, gets deleted !

Am I doing something wrong ? Or is there a way to make sure this doesn't happen?

I can definitely handle it using a workaround wherein I can fetch the current config and then update the env variables locally and then push the entire updated config, all of this through a python code etc.
But, is that the only way to do it ? Or can there be a simpler way of doing it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the intention of the documentation.

> You provide only the parameters you want to change.

`--environment` is the (singular) "parameter" that you are specifying should be changed -- not the individual variables.

The environment variables are configured *en bloc* so there is no concept of specifying only certain environment variables that you want to be different.

Comment: Ok got it. But I think, I will at least try raising a PR on boto, something like say: `selective-update-function-configuration`, to try accommodating the same :)
Thanks for the reply anyway though. Cheers!

Comment: You can try that... but the SDKs tend to fairly closely model the underlying service APIs... and [`UpdateFunctionConfiguration`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_UpdateFunctionConfiguration.html) doesn't support that, either.

Comment: yea, that's true. The actual API also does the same. However, IMHO, this would be a nice to have thing :)

Comment: Oh, agreed.  [`aws cloudfront update-distribution`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/update-distribution.html) is an other example, except that the underlying API is even more strict, requiring resubmission of a complete duplication of *all* parameters (not just what you want to change)... which I strongly suspect has roots in [this design philosophy](https://twitter.com/colmmacc/status/1039226173153103872?s=09).

Answer (score 11):

It seems not easy to partially update the environment variables for a lambda with `awscli`.

But with the usage of the [built-in JSON-based client-side filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html) that uses the [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) syntax, I found a way to achieve what I needed to do.

```sh
NEW_ENVVARS=$(aws lambda get-function-configuration --function-name your-func-name --query "Environment.Variables | merge(@, \`{\"ENV_VAR_TO_UPDATE\":\"value_here\"}\`)")

aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name your-func-name --environment "{ \"Variables\": $NEW_ENVVARS }"
```

Of course, you can update more than one environment variable with that trick.

Answer (score 10):

```
aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name my-function-name --environment Variables="{VAR1=variable_value, VAR2=variable_value}"
```

Description:Above Command will update the environment variables for the lambda function in aws.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where I wanted to update only one env variable of a function and not touch the rest.

I ended up writing a script in node and publishing it:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-lambda-update-env

It is pretty simple to use:

```
update-lambda-env KEY "My New Test Value" --stack-name myApplicationStack
```

This will only change the variable **KEY** in the functions located in the stack 
**myApplicationStack**

A better solution might be to use AWS Parameter Store if your variable is going to change often.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html

Comment: Cool tool - afraid it doesn't work with several nested stacks. I have A including B including C, where C is the lambda stack. I can apply it to B (and it will update C), but not to A.

Comment: @Roelant I am not sure I will be able to make make it work recursively. You will just have to call the script for each stack. Behind the scenes it does "aws cloudformation list-stack-resources --stack-name {mystack}"

Comment: Yes ended up writing a little boto loop around your tool to fetch me the right stacks :)